# What may cause a CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION in result of curl_easy_getinfo for CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm trying to get a response code for HTTP request inside WriteCallback. I'm sure it worked in my main app just a few days ago, but doesn't work now. However, I tried to checkout previous branch and commits in git, actually they have the same problem now. I cann't give you full reproducible code because it's too large and complex, but I can show you my test app which illustrates what I'm doing:

```
#include "curl/curl.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32")
#pragma comment(lib, "normaliz.lib")

#pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib")
namespace details {
FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };
}
extern "C" FILE* __cdecl __iob_func(void)
{
    return details::_iob;
}

using namespace std;

CURL* curl = nullptr;

size_t writeData(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream)
{
    long responseCode = -1;
    auto errorCode    = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode); // POINT 1
    if (errorCode || (responseCode != 200 && responseCode != 206)) {
        cout << "\n  writeData FAILED: errorCode: " << errorCode << ", responseCode " << responseCode << '\n';
        return 0;
    }

    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

size_t headerWriter(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    auto header = (std::string((char*)contents, size * nmemb));
    cout << "Got header: " << header;
    return size * nmemb;
}

int сurlProgressCallback(void* clientp, curl_off_t dltotal, curl_off_t dlnow, curl_off_t ultotal, curl_off_t ulnow)
{
    return CURL_PROGRESSFUNC_CONTINUE;
}

bool setupCurl(CURL* curl, const std::string& url, FILE* file)
{
    static const std::string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3202.75 "
                     "Safari/537.36 MyApp";
    bool hasError = (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, userAgent.c_str());
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL);
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeData);
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
    hasError |= (bool)curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, headerWriter);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, сurlProgressCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA, curl);
    return hasError;
}

FILE* openFile(const std::string& filePath)
{
    auto deleteSuccess = DeleteFileA(filePath.c_str());
    if (!deleteSuccess) {
        auto error = GetLastError();
        if (error != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            cout << "Failed to delete file " << filePath << ", code " << std::to_string(error) << '\n';
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    FILE* file  = nullptr;
    auto  error = fopen_s(&file, filePath.c_str(), "wb");
    if (error) {
        cout << "Cann't open file " << filePath << '\n';
    }

    return file;
}

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
        return -1;
    }

    const std::string filePath = "C:\\test-curl.txt";
    FILE*             file        = openFile(filePath);
    if (!file) {
        return -1;
    }

    const std::string url      = "https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html";
    bool              hasError = setupCurl(curl, url, file);
    if (hasError) {
        return -1;
    }

    auto errorCode = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (errorCode) {
        cout << "Curl failed: error code " << errorCode << '\n';
    } else {
        cout << "\nFinished successfully\n";
    }

    long responseCode = -1;
    errorCode    = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode); // POINT 2
    if (errorCode) {
        cout << "\n  failed to get response code\n";
    }

    fclose(file);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

I omitted some checks and proper deinitializing for brevity. This test app works as expected and it uses the same static build of libcurl as my main app. The problem is my main app gets an `CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION` error at point 1:

```
auto errorCode = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode); // errorCode == CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION
```

The `curl_easy_getinfo` returns `CURLE_OK` at point 2 in both apps. I'm sure I didn't change any system settings and I didn't make a libcurl recompilation.

Questions are: should `curl_easy_getinfo` for `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE` actually work inside write callback? If yes, what may cause it to fail and return an `CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION` error?

P.S.: I found that in my main app I'm getting `CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION` also in progress callback and write header callback.

P.P.S.: I also found that I'm getting `CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION` error for any info parameter - e.g., I tried `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_METHOD`, `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` and `CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy Grail, sorry. I'm feeling so stupid. In my main app I just forgot to update a curl handle after clearing a buffer which I pass to callback as user' structure. So `CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION` in my case actually just meant somethin like "Invalid curl handle".